# Why shouldn't users modify remote tracking branches

Tags: git, branch

http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/ says: "Remote Tracking Branches should not be modified by users (don’t set your git branch to a remote tracking branch via git checkout and then try to modify the remote tracking branch)."

First of all how does one modify a remote tracking branch other than with normal workflow? In a normal workflow I would clone a repo (`git clone something`, make changes, then `git push` which will by default push my master branch to the remote tracking branch origin/master, right? How is this different from what is described above in the link?

As described at the top I can do a `git checkout origin/master` which leaves me in a "detach HEAD" state but cannot really make any changes without creating a new branch thus I am not able to modify the remote tracking branch hence the confusion.

If you answer that then my original question on why users shouldn't modify remote tracking branches might become clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you've answered your own question.  If you attempt to checkout a remote branch, as in:

```
git checkout origin/master
```

You will be in a "detached head" state.  While you can make additional commits, there will be no local reference to them, you won't be able to push your changes, and you will probably end up losing your work (by switching to another branch and losing access to the commits you made on the detached head).

It's not an um-recoverable situation, but it's easy for a novice user to get confused.

And that's why you shouldn't modify a remote tracking branch.